# How can I achieve a colour pattern on a hair system?

Tags: texturing, color, hair

I'm looking to create patterns on top of hair like in this image. I know how to give hair systems a single colour or gradient colouring, but I would like to give the impression of shapes being painted 'on top' of it, all whilst keeping an active hair system so I can animate it. Is this possible?

Not sure if I am approaching this the wrong way.

[image]

Comment: maybe convert to mesh then use stencil brush to project the image?

Comment: that would work if i was trying to keep the hair in a fixed shape, but i wouldn’t be able to edit the hair particle properties anymore. My animation requires certain hair properties to change over time